# How to map empty array using Dozer

Tags: dozer

I am using dozer to map an array to a list which works perfectly, but when I try to map that list to an array I got a null object if the list was empty.

Here's an example:

Let's say that I have an array of type1, which has no children, so the length is 0. After mapping it to a list, I got an empty list, which is normal.

The problem start when I try to map that empty list, I got a null array, but I want to get an empty array (not null but length=0).

What can I change in the mapping file so I can get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

<mapping map-null="true" map-id="yourClassMapping" >
    <class-a>yourClass1</class-a>
    <class-b>yourClass2</class-b>
    <field map-id="list2Array">
        <a>list</a>
        <b>array</b>
        <a-hint>java.util.List</a-hint>
        <b-hint>java.util.ArrayList</b-hint>
    </field>
    ...
</mapping>
</mappings>
```